# PHP sessions not working/ SSL issue?

Tags: php, session, ssl

My site is online, but I used this code to redirect it to a coming soon page.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['en'])) {

    header("Location: /comingsoon");
    exit;

}
```

I then added third party SSL to my site and when I removed that bit of code the initial site would come up, but after the log in page the sessions are not being stored.

When I introduce that bit of code (earlier) back in it works.

This has really got me baffled.

I used this bit of code in HTAccess to redirect from HTTP to HTTPs.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Are you using `session_start();` properly?

Comment: Hi Mr SLayer, yes on every single page. It is just when I remove that initial code (redirects to .com) that it stops sending the session from log in.

Answer (score -1):

```
function redirectToHTTPS()
{
  if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on")
  {
     $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     header("Location:$redirect");
  }
}
```

//  call the above function in that page where you have to redirect to https.

Comment: Hi Irfan, thanks for your answer. Is this code to replace the HTTPs redirection that I have in the .htaccess file?

Comment: -1. The Host header and the request URI are controlled by the client. This code will provide a malicious person with an open redirect, and on some versions of PHP, an arbitrary header injection exploit. Don't use it.